# Para que serve o método ABSPATH?

Tags: php

Para que serve o método **`ABSPATH`**?

Estou fazendo um curso e apareceu a linha de código que não sei o que significa.

```
define('UP_ABSPATH', ABSPATH . '/views/_uploads' );
```

Comment: `ABSPATH` é uma constante criada por você ou pelo seu framework. A ideia deve ser fixar o caminho de algo (libs, views ou qualquer outra coisa)

Comment: Entendi, mas tem outra linha com o mesmo método.

define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ABSPATH` não é um método. Ela na verdade é uma **[constante](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.php)** criada no código PHP.

Alguns sistemas/frameworks, utilizam essas constantes pois isso auxilia a manutenção, legibilidade do código e etc.

Imagina a seguinte situação: Você tem um projeto com milhares de linhas e precisa incluir os arquivos de uma pasta, você teria que fazer a seguinte forma.

```
include "system/file1.php"
include "system/file2.php"
include "system/file3.php"
include "system/file4.php"
include "system/file5.php"
include "system/file6.php"
```

Agora imagina que, por algum motivo, você resolve trocar o nome da pasta **system**, olha o trabalho para fazer isso. Aí que entra uma das utilizações de constantes.

Dessa forma, você só precisaria alterar uma única linha para fazer efeito em todo o resto do código.

```
define("ABSPATH", "system");

include ABSPATH . "/file1.php"
include ABSPATH . "/file2.php"
include ABSPATH . "/file3.php"
include ABSPATH . "/file4.php"
include ABSPATH . "/file5.php"
include ABSPATH . "/file6.php"
```

Assim, caso você precisasse alterar o nome da pasta system, alteraria apenas o valor da constante.

---

Sobre a dúvida com `define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );`

**__FILE__** é uma constate nativa do PHP. Ela serve para indicar o caminho completo do arquivo está está sendo executado.

Ex: Você tem dois arquivos **/var/www/html/index.php** e **/var/www/html/index2.php**

Quando você acessa o arquivo `index.php` http://www.example.com/index.php, o PHP, automaticamente, atribui o valor **/var/www/html/index.php** para a constante **__FILE__**

O mesmo ocorre quando você acessa http://www.example.com/index2.php. O PHP, automaticamente, atribui o valor à __FILE__ como sendo "/var/www/html/index2.php"

Já o comando [**dirname**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) serve para capturar o nome do diretório que está localizado o arquivo atual.

Caso o arquivo executado seja "/var/www/html/index2.php", o dirname retorna apenas o nome "html"

Comment: Cara muito obrigada que explicação excelente, só fiquei na duvida dessa outra linha que apareceu no código define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( FILE ) );

Comment: @sol1010lua editei minha resposta. Adicionei uma breve explicação sobre o código `define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );`.

Comment: Explicação muito boa onde me ajudou e muito a compreender esses códigos, vlw